# How to handle modification on MIT Licenced project

Tags: licensing, copyright, mit-license

I'm about to fork an `MIT licenced` project, I'm planning to use it as a starter. I was wondering how I have to handle the licence.

#### What I understand

1. When I will mimifie my javascript application, I'll have to include `Copyright 201x (c) Original Owner` in the header.

#### Questions

1. Can I modify the `LICENCE` file to include my name, and most important, how can I include my name?
2. Where do I specify what is under `Original Owner` copyright and what is under mine, without specifying in each file, can I be more generic, something like:

- `Starter project: Copyright 201x (c) Original Owner`
- `All other source code: Copyright 201x (c) My name here`

Comment: This would be of interest: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/195138/203769

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MIT licence copyright notice for derived works](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/195076/mit-licence-copyright-notice-for-derived-works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. All you have to is just to write the last original version and give a copyright to the original author. Then under it write your name, year and copyright for the modified version. That's all you have to do. You don't have to specify files. You can even change the license for the modified version.

However it all is on how you interpret the license, as I'm not a lawyer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right there in the license. You can do pretty much whatever you want, as long as you preserve the Copyright notice (the line(s) starting with Copyright) and the Permission notice (everything else, except the all-caps warranty disclaimer). Usually you'd also want to preserve the warranty disclaimer, but you're not required to.

If you want your own modifications to the code to also be MIT licensed, you can simply add your own Copyright line beneath the existing one.

Whatever you do, you are not allowed to modify the existing Copyright notice.